# C++ DBI Class - best/developer friendliest style

Tags: c++, sql, coding-style, dbi

In our current project, we need some high level DBI for different databases. It should provide the following features:

- **in memory cache** - the DBI should be able to cache all reads, and update the cache on writing calls (the application we are coding on is heavy threaded, and needs fast access to the current data all the time). The memory cache will be based on `boost::multi_index`
- **automatic sql building** - We don't want to parse a sql statement to lookup in the memory cache

As we need to provide functions for: defining a table layout, do selects, do inserts, do updates, joins, ..., the interface will get very complex.

We need a good way to invoke the interface function.

There are many styles around, but we could not find any useful for our usage.

Here a few examples:

**SOCI**

```
sql << "select name, salary from persons where id = " << id, into(name), into(salary);
```

We don't want some SQL statements, so we would have to define `what` and `from` a different way.

**pqxx**

```
Conn.prepare("select_salary",
    "select name, salary from persons where id = $1")
    ((string)"integer",prepare::treat_direct);
```

The heavy usage of the overloaded `operator()` is just ugly, but it could work for us too.

Any suggestions how to *design* the interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using object relational mapping? Here's some code fragment ideas off the top of my head - I've only done this in Python, never in C++, and only for fairly simple databases. There's a [list of frameworks on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software#C.2B.2B) that should avoid too much wheel-related R&D.

```
class people: public dbi_table
{
    // id column handled by dbi_table.
    name: string_column;
    salary: money_column;
};

class cost_center: public dbi_table
{
    name: string_column;
    office: foreign_key<offices>;
};

class people_cost_center_link: public link_table
{
    // Many-many relationships.
};
```

Then you can manipulate records as objects, all the relational stuff is handled by the framework. Querying is done by defining a query object and then getting an iterator to the results (see [the ODB wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODB_(C%2B%2B)) for a code example).

Comment: Thank you for your ideas, but we already evaluated this. ODB uses a own compiler/preprocessor  , the most ORM frameworks are using database dependent datatypes and more. I like the coding style to use with ODB, but right now, i have no idea how to implement that without the need of a own compiler/preprocessor. As we need to query the internal cache as well, we must be able to map the sql datatypes to the corresponding internal types. Maybe you.

Comment: So if we rule out using an existing framework, it seems that the biggest problem is the query syntax, correct? Inserts, updates and retrieval by ID can all be handled by your table, column, etc objects. What if you implemented a "search_by<field_name>" method for each table which basically ran "if not in cache then do sql select * from table where field_name is blah"?

Comment: The `search_by<field_name>` sounds great. I'll have a deeper look at this tonight

Comment: @Thomas, ORM frameworks in other languages also use a meta-compiler, btw, ODB compiler will build to c++ source, which you will then build with your g++ or whatever compiler you use. I don't see what problem do you see with that. It seems wonderful to me

Comment: @lurscher: Read my question. We need to implement a cache (read/write) and the application has plugin-support. So 3rd party plugins should not mess up with building a own cache.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (and it'd be good in c++ point of view, dunno if it's correct database stuff):

```
struct Handle { int id; }
class DBI 
{
public:
   virtual Handle select(int column_id)=0;
   virtual Handle select(int column1, int column2)=0;
   virtual Handle id(int id)=0;
   virtual Handle join(Handle i1, Handle i2)=0;
   virtual void execute_query(Handle i)=0;
};
```

Usually these functions would be implemented like this:

```
Handle select(int column_id) {
   return new_handle(new SelectNode(column_id));
}
```

where new_handle function would just insert SelectNode to std::vector or std::map and create an handle for it.